# Need to constantly "Restart All Services" on WAMP Server

Tags: http, wamp

I have a WAMP server setup for our intranet page here, we have a few thousand people accessing it daily.

At random times all through the day the server would stop working. It stays green but I cannot connect to the site. I have to "Restart All Services" and it would work again for awhile.

I have no clue how to begin diagnosing this problem.

Comment: Sounds like your server is overloaded. Can we get some more information about the box? How much RAM? What does the CPU look like when Apache hangs? Show us your httpd.conf file. Do you have any errors in the PHP log around when it hangs? Perhaps you just have one bad script bringing it down. http://www.howtoforge.com/configuring_apache_for_maximum_performance

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This server is actually running on a virtual machine. It had around 2GB of RAM allocated but I just increased that to 5GB, hopefully that will help. The VMWare performance log does show a spike in CPU usage around the time before the server stops working. I could not get PHP Error log it says the PHP Log file does not exist...

Comment: Ended having just too many issues with WAMP in my environment so I switched to IIS Web Server 2008 and transferred all my WAMP stuff to it. Being running very smooth. Thanks.